# Different rounding with println and printf

Tags: java, double, precision

The first line below will print `0.8999999999999999` because of precision loss, this is clear. But the second line will print `0.9`, I just do not understand why. Shouldn't there be the same problem with this calculation?

```
System.out.println(2.00-1.10);
System.out.printf("%f",2.00-1.10);
```

Comment: There is the same problem, but it is being hidden by lower precision output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing something as using System.out.printf(), if you do not explicit formatting widths then default behavior of printf in C (which is 6 decimal places if not explicitly specified)

So if you will not specify any number to `%f` then by default it will print only 1 character. However if you want to change the number after the decimal then you need to specify it like `%.2f`, this will print the number to 2 decimal places.

So it is similar to writing like

```
System.out.printf("%f",2.00-1.10);
```

or

```
System.out.printf("%.1f",2.00-1.10);
```

As the general syntax for format specifier for float is:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][argsize]typechar
```

**On a side note:-**

Also there is a [formatter class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) in Java for this.

> An interpreter for printf-style format strings. This class provides
>   support for layout justification and alignment, common formats for
>   numeric, string, and date/time data, and locale-specific output.
>   Common Java types such as byte, BigDecimal, and Calendar are
>   supported. Limited formatting customization for arbitrary user types
>   is provided through the Formattable interface.

From the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#l10n%20algorithm)

> If the precision is not specified then the default value is 6. If the
>   precision is less than the number of digits which would appear after
>   the decimal point in the string returned by Float.toString(float) or
>   Double.toString(double) respectively, then the value will be rounded
>   using the round half up algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

This output is the due to reason of `round half up` operation of floating format `%f`. If you go through the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#l10n%20algorithm), than you will get

> If the precision is not specified then the default value is 6. If the
>   precision is less than the number of digits which would appear after
>   the decimal point in the string returned by **Float.toString(float) or
>   Double.toString(double)** respectively, **then the value will be rounded
>   using the round half up algorithm**.

Answer (score 3):

according to me, the format %f prints 1 character.
the fact that it prints 0.9 is standard mathematical rounding behavior